# compound numbers from one array into another

Tags: javascript, arrays

Ultimately, I'm looking to create two arrays, manipulating data from one to the other.

--

I have been trying unsuccessfully (for around 3 weekends) to create an array based on the length of a variable; in this case, I've made it **155**...this step is complete now.

*I want to use the array as a reference later on, therefore have chosen not to manipulate itself.*

I then want to create another array that takes sequential numbers from the first array to apply what would essentially be compound interest.

**Visual**

array 1 (sequence of days to run):
1, 2, 3, 4, 5

array 2 (compounded numbers):
1, 3, 6, 10, 15

I am struggling to get this math action to work. Furthermore, I am wanting the compound component to be a variable too. This might be fed into the calculation as a variable called **variance**

```
let dateDifference = 155;

// creates empty array
const savingLength = [];

// iterates through length of array
for(i = 0; i < dateDifference; i++)
{
  // creates maximum days ARRAY until end of saving term
  // adds array index as array value, +1 to create iteration of days in base10
  base10 = i+1;
  savingLength.push(base10); 

}

// creates a savingAmount array that is populated with data from savingLength array
const savingAmount = savingLength.map(function(savingLength){
  // does calculation on savingAmount element and returns it

  // desired CALC. compound interest

  return savingLength + mathBit();
});


function mathBit() {
  savingAmount.forEach(saving => {

    y = saving - 1;
    x = example.startAmount;
    saving = x + y;

  });
}
console.log(savingAmount);
console.log(savingLength);
```

Comment: What do you need the `[1, 2, 3, ... 155]` array for? Why not just `i => i < 155 ? i + 1 : undefined` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently, `mathBit` isn't returning anything, so when your `.map` function does `return savingLength + mathBit();`, it won't work.

It would probably be easier to use the triangular number sequence to calculate the second array: `a(n) = (n * (n + 1)) / 2)`

`Array.from` allows you to create arrays from scratch without any reassignment or mutation. Try something like this:

```js
const dateDifference = 5;
const savingLength = Array.from(
  { length: dateDifference },
  (_, i) => i + 1
);
const savingAmount = savingLength.map(i => (i * (i + 1)) / 2);
console.log(savingLength);
console.log(savingAmount);
```

It's not clear what exactly you want with the variance, but one possibility would be to just tweak the triangular number formula - multiply the result by something:

```js
const dateDifference = 5;
const savingLength = Array.from(
  { length: dateDifference },
  (_, i) => i + 1
);
const variance = 2;
const savingAmount = savingLength.map(i => variance * (i * (i + 1)) / 2);
console.log(savingLength);
console.log(savingAmount);
```

Comment: Thanks for your solution. it seems to have ticked all the boxes. though I'm still not sure why triangular number sequences are even a thing. What is the general purpose of them, other than to solve my problem?

Comment: They come up often enough in math. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangular_number https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-practical-use-of-triangular-numbers-in-the-real-world